# Ionic 2: storing the response from an http GET request

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, get, ionic2, eventbrite

I'm working on an app and have an event provider set up. I'm using the Eventbrite API to obtain a pool of events happening in a city.  I'm running into difficulty trying to figure out how to execute the get request and store it in a variable. Here is the URL of the request:

```
https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=Atlanta&expand=organizer,venue&token={MY_TOKEN}
```

Here is my provider so far:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {NativeStorage} from "ionic-native";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the EventProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class EventProvider {
  data:any;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.data = null;
    //console.log('Hello EventProvider Provider');
  }

  public getCityEvents(city) {
    var event = {id: "", name: "", start: "", end: "", latitude: "", longitude: "", venue:""};
    NativeStorage.getItem('event')
      .then(function (data) {
        alert("data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        alert("data id: " + data.id);

        event = {
          id = data.id,
          name = data.name,
          start = data.start,
          end = data.end,
          latitude = data.latitude,
          longitude = data.longitude,
          venue = data.venue
        };


      this.http.get("https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=Atlanta&expand=organizer,venue&token=VMGQGYQUIO3IKNS75BD4").subscribe( data =>{
        console.log(data);
        },
      error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
      })
  }

}
```

I simply just want to store the JSON response from this get request in a variable for now. Can someone please offer some help?

Comment: `this.data = event` should do it... but you need to use an arrow function, `(params) => expression or block`, instead of a `function` expression. If you don't have a transpiler Available to you, alias this to a temporary variable outside the closure and reference it inside the closure. The this reference is dynamically scoped inside of `function`

Comment: sorry I don't quite understand. I am getting the response I want when typing the url in a browser but I'm not sure if what I have is actually working. The event variable i defined contains the eventual data fields I want to get out of the JSON but the JSON response has many other fields too. Could you elaborate on your solution more in terms of the code i posted?

Comment: Just try the approach in ajai Jothi's answer or in my comment

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow function in `NativeStorage.getItem('event').then((data) => { ... }` and you can access actual context `this` inside your `http` callback.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {NativeStorage} from "ionic-native";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the EventProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class EventProvider {
  data:any;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.data = null;
    //console.log('Hello EventProvider Provider');
  }

  public getCityEvents(city) {
    var event = {id: "", name: "", start: "", end: "", latitude: "", longitude: "", venue:""};
    NativeStorage.getItem('event')
      .then((data) => {
        alert("data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        alert("data id: " + data.id);

        event = {
          id = data.id,
          name = data.name,
          start = data.start,
          end = data.end,
          latitude = data.latitude,
          longitude = data.longitude,
          venue = data.venue
        };


      this.http.get("https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=Atlanta&expand=organizer,venue&token=VMGQGYQUIO3IKNS75BD4").subscribe( data =>{
        console.log(data);
        //variable assignment
        this.data = data;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
      })
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

create functions

```
  getData() {
return this.http.get("https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=Atlanta&expand=organizer,venue&token=VMGQGYQUIO3IKNS75BD4")
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }


  private extractData(res: Response) {
let body = res.json();
return body.data || { };
  }
```

and then subscribe

```
  this.getData()
                     .subscribe(
                       data => console.log(data);
                       error =>  console.log(error));
  }
```

refer to [angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) your get works from postman.

Comment: That is straight-up wrong, by passing unbound methods you do not solve the problem in the OP which is specifically related to lexical closure over `this`. On the contrary, you propagate the mistake into a suggested pattern. Also passing methods like that is an absolutely terrible coding practice regardless. Imitating the angular Doc's when they are wrong is just pointless